# SVN - list of changed files ignoring whitespaces

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there any way in SVN, to list the files that are changed while ignoring the ones that have only whitespace changes.
I already tried, without success, the following:

```
    svn diff -x --ignore-all-space --summarize > changed_files.txt
```

To contextualize, here is the scenario, as an example:
I have some java classes (.java) that are generated and sometimes, depending on some configurations (like formatter in the IDE), a lot of files are marked as changes, though most of them have only whitespace changes.

The best would even be able to filter this directly on the SVN client such as TortoiseSVN, so I could commit only the files that have real changes and ignore the rest.

Comment: are you generating classes (.class) or code (.java)? You didn't say it was java, but the question holds... genearting source or bytecode.

Comment: Are java classes, source code (.java files). But the goal of the question is to be more generic, since it can apply to anything. I rephrased the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some java classes (.java) that are generated and sometimes, depending on some configurations (like formatter in the IDE), a lot of files are marked as changes, though most of them have only whitespace changes.

The best answer is not to store generated `*.java` files in your code. We have several projects that use [WSDL](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html) files that create Java files that have to be compiled later. We simply setup our Ant build to generate those files if they need to be generated.

Not exactly what you're looking for, but you're finding out one of the reasons why you shouldn't have generated files in your repository.

Comment: This is not really the case, since the generated classes can also be then edited manually, and still being generated the parts not marked as edited.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the suggestion from previous answer from **@nosid**, I created a batch script for Windows, which uses a temporary file to write the result of svn status and svn diff. Maybe there is a better way to do it without using temporary files, but this works fine:

```
@echo off
set dir=%1
set tempDir=%TEMP%
set svnFileStatus=%tempDir%\svn-file-status
set svnFileChanges=%tempDir%\svn-file-changes
set fileType=*.java

for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s %dir%\%fileType%') do (
  svn status %%a > %svnFileStatus%
  call :CheckStatus %svnFileStatus% %%a
)
goto :eof

:CheckStatus
if %~z1 == 0 (
  rem skip
) else (
  svn diff -x --ignore-all-space %2 > %svnFileChanges%
  call :CheckDiff %svnFileChanges% %2
)
goto :eof

:CheckDiff
if %~z1 == 0 (
  svn changelist ignore-on-commit %2
)
goto :eof
```

This script is adding the files to the ignore-on-commit changelist. One can then revert this changelist. Alternatively the script can be adjusted to revert the files directly if you feel confident, but I prefer to do it in 2-steps.

To use the script, simply copy it into a batch files, and call it from the Windows CLI passing by argument the directory where to search, something like this:

```
check-empty-changes.bat <svn-working-copy-directory>
```

The script is configured to search for java files, but you can change it to use other file extensions, setting the variable **%fileType%** propertly.